# Can't see my SSD when installing

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install elementary OS on the new XPS 9560.

It comes with windows 10 home. I have installed it, and I have resized my SSD by about half.

I currently have around 480 GB of unallocated space.

I then rufus up a bootable USB with correct hash.

I then boot it up and get to the install mode. But when I come to the part of "Installation type" it doesn't see any device and I don't have access to gparted or anything.

Is this a common occurance?

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to install E OS on my dell xps 9550 and found the solution for your problem while searching for mine (how ironic)

1 Reset BIOS settings to default

2 Boot windows

3 Run command 'msconfig '

4 Tab 'boot' and tap 'safe mode'

5 Restart, enter BIOS and switch RAID to AHCI

6 Restart and windows will boot in Safe mode.

7 Run msconfig and untap safe mode.

8 Restart,  insert USB and boot ubuntu.

9 This time it will locatie your SSD drive.

**Pls note that this will not work for a HDD**

Comment: This should work... AHCI is one of the key values for disk drives and linux

Answer (score 0):

For my small company, the Dell XPS 13's are a great fit but don't come with Linux on the cutting edge touchscreens / etc.   Linux / elementary / manjaro / ubuntu are all best for our engineers and GIS crew, but there still remain some industry-specific software we need windows for (Pix4d).

We've finally perfected the dual boot installation process after destroying and reinstalling too many OS's... here's what we do....  *Most used machine: Dell XPS 13, Windows 10 already installed, no linux yet, often we use Elementary OS*

**The Definitive XPS 13 dual-boot how to :**

- Make sure Linux USB boot image is created using WINDOWS (so it boots UEFI style, we use Rufus)
- Windows Partition Manager --> shrink so unallocated space is available for Linux
- Windows Settings --> Power Options --> Advanced --> Change what power button does --> Allow changes to settings --> turn off fastboot
- Run 'msconfig' --> boot tab --> safe mode to ON
- Restart, enter BIOS and switch RAID to AHCI (use *f2* on dell logo)
- Restart and windows will boot in Safe mode
- Run msconfig again and unselect safe mode
- Restart, insert USB *the moment* the computer power toggles
- *F2* again into bios settings, make sure boot sequence is USB first, Windows second
- Apply and exit
- Allow system to boot from and install Linux
- When installer asks about 'partition' --> 'boot alongside windows'
- let installer do the rest
- Restart
- You're done.  Choose OS and go.